# How do I pull data from an excel sheet to my React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, excel

I created this static html/bootstrap [website](https://clicksgadget.netlify.app/) a while back and I am now rebuilding it in react as a side project (just started learning react).

For the [products page](https://clicksgadget.netlify.app/products.html), I currently just have static data and in my [code](https://github.com/brian-o-mars/clicks-gadget), everything is hardcoded. An idea I had is to have the data for each product in an excel sheet and connect that sheet to my react app somehow so I can update the data in the excel sheet with a new entry and a new product gets created on the website. Is this possible? If yes, how do I go about this?

I am thinking of using the excel sheet to create an API and then just use fetch/state management to pull the data from the API in JSON format and display it. Does this make any sense?

I'm really new to programming, so I would appreciate some advice and probably some resources to achieve this.

Comment: If you use google sheets, you can get your data from that spreadsheet from your web app by making a GET request to the google sheets JSON endpoint for your excel doc ([here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/cjn-google-sheets-as-json-endpoint/) is an example on how to get that link).  To make the GET request you can use something like `fetch()` or axios. Never tried this, so there is a possibility that you'll be blocked by CORS depending on how the google sheets endpoint is configured on Google's side.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @NickParsons. Google has discontinued the sheet v3 API used in the article but I was able to implement this in v4. Got my data perfectly!